# How to profile a Java program run from start to finish?

Tags: java, profiling, performance-testing

I have a Java program that runs for only about 20-30 seconds and I want to profile it.

Firing up the jvisualvm profiler manually at each start is not reliable, because you lose several seconds operating the UI.

Is there a way to profile the entire exectution, like the old `-Xhprof:cpu=samples` which no longer works?

Comment: You can with flight recorder which I prefer. https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/jmc-5-5/jfr-runtime-guide/run.htm#JFRRT177

Comment: @PeterLawrey Why not make an Answer of that comment, so we can close this Question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Flight Recorder you can add to the command line

```
-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder 
-XX:FlightRecorderOptions=defaultrecording=true,dumponexit=true,settings=profile
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/jmc-5-5/jfr-runtime-guide/run.htm#JFRRT176

It only records the memory allocation on a new TLAB, so I make it much smaller than the default to get more samples.

```
-XX:TLABSize=128k
```

You need to run `jmc` from the `$JAVA_HOME/bin` directory to open the `.jfr` file created.

I find this harder to use than VisualVM, but produces much more detailed results with less noise. i.e. you get far fewer allocations causes by the profiler itself.